# how to get value of each row in php/mysql where condition is by it's category

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to get the values of a few rows but i am only getting the value of the first row. any suggestion?

table structure

PROD_ID   |   PROD_NAME   |   PROD_VAL   |   PROC_CAT

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM TABLE_PRODUCT WHERE PROD_CAT='general'";

if($set = $db->Execute($sql)){

$prod=$set->fields['PROD_VAL'];
}

//then i get the value of each row

$test1=$prod['product1']; <- this is PROD_NAME -- Row 1
$test2=$prod['product2']; <- this is PROD_NAME -- Row 2

i am able to get the value of row 1 but not 2. what i am doing wrong?
```

Comment: Are you using ADOdb??

Comment: yepp i am using adodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch rows data you can use

```
foreach($set as $row)
{
// get values here

}
```

Or call `MoveNext()` before reading another record.

Comment: hey, i am not able to get this working. i need to specify a var for each so i need it like $test1=['PROD_NAME'];

Comment: if($set = $db->Execute($sql)){$test1=$set[PROD_NAME]; $set->MoveNext();$test2=$set[PROD_NAME];}